# Can vinegar be used to clean wood (a porous surface) after it has been cleaned with germicidal bleach?

Tags: cleaning

I recently cleaned moldy air vents and hardwood floor with diluted germicidal bleach water (1/3 cup bleach to 1 gall). I would like to go back in with vinegar to make sure the mold stays gone, mostly as peace of mind for me. Is it safe after 24+hours to clean with vinegar? I’m also concerned that the areas may not be completely 100% dry from the bleach mixture.

Comment: Bleach and vinegar do not go well. You do not want chlorinated acetic acid products.

Comment: I’m wondering if the bleach being diluted and applied over 24 hours ago if it’s okay to spray with vinegar

Comment: Sodium hypochlorite (bleach) is a solid, it does not evaporate. It is sold in solution. It decomposes slowly. Give it a week.

Comment: Actually, AChem is confusing calcium hypochlorite (a solid) with aqueous sodium hypochlorite as commercially prepared from the electrolysis of aqueous NaCl. Solid NaOCl exists but very unstable (as in explosive).

Comment: I am not confusing bleaching powder with sodium hypochlorite. **Both are solids**! Since sodium hypochlorite is unstable at room temperature, it is solid as a stablized solution at high pH. Yes, it is made electrolytically. In short *bleach does not evaporate* from surfaces.

Comment: Solid NaOCl is not sold as a commercial bleach due to its extreme instability. One only prepares dilute aqueous solutions!

Comment: Further,  aqueous NaOCl rapidly decomposes to just NaCl in solutions exposed to light, dust,  and transition metal-rich tap water, so it does not stick around.

Comment: More precisely, boiling down aqueous NaOCl is a path to NaCl and some NaClO3. This is a commonly known (but inefficient) method for chlorate preparation.

Comment: I’ll wait a week before using vinegar on the wood. I’m very very novice and ignorant with chemistry but thank you for the information and assistance! Pesky mold.